# how to get negotiated information from SSL handshake in JSSE

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I want to record things like client sent tls version, server preferred version, server preferred cipher suite in JSSE. how to do this? 
Note that I can only use Java code to do this.Parsing log files are not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add **-Djavax.net.debug=all** flag to your java execution string and it will dump all that info into the console.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: Sorry that I can not parse log files or stand output. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this information is available is via the `javax.net.debug` system property. If you can't parse that output all you can get is the data in the resulting `SSLSession`, which consists of what the negotiated protocol and cipher suite were, and the peer certificates. You can also have a look at your own `SSLSocket`'s enabled protocols and cipher suites, but I don't see where it's going to get you.